# how to keep the four last letters of a series?

Tags: python, pandas, list, series

I have a series of words of which i only want to keep the four last letters:

```
X = data['stem']
0       abalanz
1       abander
2       abandon
3        abanic
4        abarat

3029       best
3030        bib
3031       bolb
3032        Laz
3033       zurz
```

I tried str.replace but it had no effect on the series

```
X = pd.Series(X).str.replace('[-4:]', '', regex=False)
```

I tried to convert the series to a list, then operate on it, but this only keep the four last items of the list.

```
test = [X]
plop = [x[-4:] for x in test]
[3030     bib
 3031    bolb
 3032     Laz
 3033    zurz
 Name: stem, dtype: object]
```

What I don't understand is this function works when I use it on an other list

```
test = ['abbbb','acccc','adddd']
plop = [x[-4:] for x in test]
['bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd']
```

Comment: `test = [X]` **does not** convert a series into a list.

Comment: Nothing to replace here. You want to slice the strings: `df.stem.str[-4:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the column (series) into string and do a slice

```
X = data['stem'].str[-4:]
```

Result:

```
0    lanz
1    nder
2    ndon
3    anic
4    arat
5    zurz
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
X = data['stem'].apply(lambda x: x[-4:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it worked for me.

```
li = ['abalanz', 'abander', 'abandon', 'best', 'bib']
df = pd.DataFrame(li, columns=['stem'])

df

    stem
0  abalanz
1  abander
2  abandon
3     best
4      bib

df['stem'] = df['stem'].apply(lambda row: row[-4:])

df
   stem
0  lanz
1  nder
2  ndon
3  best
4   bib
```